# Change MS Access CSV Export Field Delimiter with Macros (Visual Basic)

Tags: mysql, ms-access, csv, export, delimiter

I have an **access database** in which I'm trying to export all of it's tables to **CSV format** so I can import them into a MySQL database.

I have **extremely limited knowledge of Visual Basic** & have managed to find a macro module (on the net) which will let me export all tables at once.

```
Public Sub exportAllChangeDelim()

Dim obj As AccessObject, dbs As Object

Set dbs = Application.CurrentData
    For Each obj In dbs.AllTables
        If Left(obj.Name, 4) <> "MSys" Then
            DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , obj.Name, obj.Name & ".csv", false
        End If
    Next obj
End Sub
```

Is there a **simple way** in which I can change the default field delimiter which is:

"

to something custom for example:

{}

The reason Is I'm having trouble with content inside fields I'm trying to export as they sometimes contain speech marks and this disrupts the field count when importing into MySQL.

Apologies for the long winded question!

Comment: You can use an export specification, however, you might find the easiest thing is to simply write the data straight from MS Access to MySQL. eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442915/what-is-the-best-way-to-synchronize-data-between-ms-access-and-mysql/443003#443003

Comment: Thanks Remou. However I don't need to run both databases parallel to one another I just need to simply export and re-import the data into mysql, if I can just change the delimiter (if possible) everything will work as expected

Comment: Unless you want to set up an export specification for each table, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13482242/create-comma-separated-file-csv-from-access-scheduled-daily-from-windows/13483597#13483597